# Custom WordPress Query sorting function

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I am trying to let users to sort a custom WP query but I can't get it working so maybe somebody know what I am doing wrong?

I am using this as a custom query:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'        => 'vacation',
        'meta_key'          => get_query_var('meta_key'),
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'order'             => get_query_var('order'),
        'posts_per_page'   => -1
    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
```

And i use this as HTML links to order:

```
<a href="?meta_key=bedrooms?order=asc">Bedrooms ASC</a>
<a href="?meta_key=bedrooms?order=desc">Bedrooms DESC</a>
```

The URL will change but I don't see any ordering of the bedrooms from high to low or low to high when I click one of the two links.

Comment: Is your meta key value "integer" or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML the href is wrong. You have to use & when you are passing multiple parameters. Like this:

`<a href="?meta_key=bedrooms&order=asc">Bedrooms ASC</a>`

`<a href="?meta_key=bedrooms&order=desc">Bedrooms DESC</a>`

Comment: this is change something when i click the links now but still not in order from the low to high bedroom numbers.

Comment: i tryed both. 'meta_value_num' and 'meta_value' but same outcome.

Comment: And have you tried by changing 'order' => get_query_var('order') to 'order' => 'ASC' or 'order => 'DESC'? To check if you see something changing.

Comment: Now i did and its not working but if i do it just like "'meta_key' => 'bedrooms'", "'orderby' => 'meta_value'" and "'order' => 'DESC'" (or ASC) then everything is ordering when i refresh the page.

Comment: Can you change get_query_var('order') to $_GET['order'] and get_query_var('meta_key') to $_GET['meta_key'] ?

Comment: That is working thank you! Can you maybe explain a little why this working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190760/discussion-between-ben-goossens-and-maanstraat).

Answer (score 0):

If your meta value is integer type then just change the "orderby" => "meta_value" to "meta_value" => "meta_value_num".

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'vacation',
    'meta_key'          => get_query_var('meta_key'),
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => get_query_var('order'),
    'posts_per_page'   => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi @robi this wont work also.  it refreshed the page but everything stays the same. The "meta_key" is a costum field from ACF and have the values from 0 to 20.